# how to add frames in html and align it?

Tags: html

I have many separate HTML files. Now I want to combine them in a single window. How to do that?

Comment: thou shall not make use of frames for these reasons:
- probably difficulties with bookmarks
- google crawler might have difficulties indexing the site
- they look awful (not only scrolling issues)

Answer (score 1):

Before you really commit to using frames in your design, I would read [why frames are evil](http://www.html-faq.com/htmlframes/?framesareevil). If you still want to use them after that, at least you're informed.

Here are all the tags that you'll need for using frames within your pages:

```
Tag      Description
<frameset>  Defines a set of frames
<frame>  Defines a sub window (a frame)
<noframes>  Defines a noframe section for browsers that do not handle frames
<iframe>    Defines an inline sub window (frame)
```

For more information and examples on how to use these tags, read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_frames.asp) or [here](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/frames.php).

Comment: hey.. some of my html files are not displaying in internet explorer..  before i used mozilla firefox to display..wat to do?

Comment: Are they still working in Firefox? If so, step back through the changes you made until you can more specifically identify the issue; we can't really help if you don't provide more details. 

Honestly, you could probably save yourself a lot of headaches if you skip using frames altogether... what drove you to decide to use them in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what do you want to achieve.

In most cases, the best way to do that is using some kind of server-side scripting or SSI, concatenating those files on server-side and returning a single, combined HTML file.

If you have to combine them client-side, you first should check whether [`<object/>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#edef-OBJECT) elements suits your needs (especially take a look at [‘Notes on embedded documents’](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.5)).

If you need more advanced behavior, you probably would need to use [frames](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html) (either full `<frameset/>` or floating `<iframe/>`) but note that this module might be considered unadvisable and thus it was removed from HTML4 Strict and XHTML.